# Is there a way to do multi-tenant Swagger?

Tags: spring-boot, swagger

I'm working on a Spring Boot application that needs to be migrated to being multi-tenant. One of the biggest changes is the concept of core vs extension models. The core model contains a data structure common to all tenants, then they can each extend the core model with additional fields that meet their specific business needs.

Pretty much everything is good to go with this, but I'm getting tripped up by Swagger. It's a corporate mandate that all our services have good Swaggers, and to be blunt I'm just having a very hard time figuring out a solution.

First, in order to handle the dynamic nature of the payload structure, we're not using Spring's automatic serialization of POJOs to JSON. We're doing it manually, in order to handle separating/combining the core and extension models. This means our controller methods pretty much look like this:

```
public String method(HttpServletRequest request) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

Right away, that cripples a lot of how SpringFox Swagger auto-magically identifies the API structure.

But then there's the fact that the request/response bodies for these methods vary. For different tenants, the structure will be slightly different. The APIs themselves are unchanged, the core model is always the same, but different sets of extension data are in play.

Are there any SpringFox/Swagger features that may help with this?

Answer (score 0):

Could you use a combination of POJOs with an embedded `Map<String, Object>` for tenant specific extensions? You could then document the core model fields.

e.g.

```
@ApiModel(value = "MyPoJo", description = "My POJO")
@Builder
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Value
public class MyPoJo {
  @ApiModelProperty(value = "My string field", required = true)
  String string;
  @ApiModelProperty(value = "My integer field")
  int integer;
  @ApiModelProperty(value = "Tenant specific custom attributes")
  Map<String, Object> customAttributes;
}
```

Comment: This is an interesting idea, the problem is we don't have POJOs for everything. This is a configurable solution, where only the core data is explicitly in code, and then we have extension configuration files that allows for handling the serialization/deserialization of the extension data. Still, thanks for the idea.